# default .ppt file in a program so every installation will have them

Tags: java, netbeans

I’m doing a little Java project that deals with files (ppt files ), and I want to incorporate this files in the program (jar) so that those file can be open on every computer without having to add them all the time.
I have try adding them to the source file but it doesn't work they don't open.

It's there a way so that once I create the jar of the project I can run it always (with the file in the jar ) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want but if you have an executable jar and include your file in the jar then you should be able to use [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(defaultFilePathInJar)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) to get an inputstream. Then do whatever you want with that stream.

Comment: i have a J Table with 300 ppt file in this project and i want to make it that by taking the jar file around I can open this files without having to add them every time I change the computer on which I'm running the program